# Spring security redirect to another context on logout

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring security to login and logout.My requirement is I need to redirect to the other context after successful log out.

```
<security:logout logout-url="/spring/logout" logout-success-url="/spring1" />
```

But it is not redirecting to the different context.Is there any way I can redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register a LogoutSuccessHandler and have that do the redirect:

```
public class RedirectingLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, 
         HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        String basePath = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName()
                + (request.getServerPort() != 80 ? ":" + request.getServerPort() : "");
        String otherContext = "/spring1";

        response.sendRedirect(basePath + "/" + otherContext);
    }
}
```

Register this as a bean and point the security config to it:

```
<logout
  logout-url="/perform_logout"
  success-handler-ref="redirectingLogoutSuccessHandler " />
```

Comment: even in the othercontext. the old context is showing in request.getContextPath()